Unable to access LAN behind Windows peer from remote Android peer
been trying the entire weekend to get Wireguard to work the way I want to no avail. I want my phone to be able to see my home LAN, the Android phone will see and connect to the Windows peer and can access its services; but can't reach the rest of the local LAN. I want my Windows peer to give the Android peer access to 192.168.1.x LAN.

I have my modem/router configured to forward incoming UDP port 51820 to my Windows peer.
I have allowed Wireguard executable in the Windows Firewall.
Accessing a service (like FTP/HTTP server) on Windows peer from Android works.
Can ping back and forth both Windows peer and Android peer between each other.
Can ping host 192.168.1.175 no problem from Windows peer.
I enabled the Windows Routing and Remote access service
Changed Windows Firewall rule File and Printer sharing (Echo ICMPv4 IN) from subnet local only to subnet any.
Changed Windows Firewall rule File and Printer Sharing (SMB-In) from subnet local only to subnet any.
I also tried with Windows Defender Firewall completely disabled.
When I ping 192.168.1.x from Android I can see RX go up at Windows side, so I'm fairly confident the phone is sending the 192.168.1.x through tunnel.

I've tried tons of different "AllowedIps", tried changing MTU sizes, tried changing DNS, tried different IPs, netranges.
I think Windows is not doing the NAT part? I dont get it what is wrong?
Windows peer:
[Interface]
PrivateKey = 0EHx
(PublicKey = FQSx)
ListenPort = 51820
Address = 10.20.10.1/24

[Peer]
PublicKey = 5tTx
AllowedIPs = 10.20.10.0/24

Android peer:
[Interface]
PrivateKey = IOJx
(PubKey = 5tTx)
Address = 10.20.10.2/24

[Peer]
PublicKey = FQSx
EndPoint = EXTERNAL/WAN-IP:51820
AllowedIPs = 10.20.10.0/24, 192.168.1.0/24

I have this Ping app installed on my Android phone which comes with a Traceroute button. When I press that on the 192.168.1.175 address, sometimes it shows 1 hop to 10.20.10.1, but that's it.
For as far I can tell Windows has forwarding enabled:
PS> Get-NetIPInterface | select ifIndex,InterfaceAlias,AddressFamily,ConnectionState,Forwarding | Sort-Object -Property IfIndex | Format-Table

ifIndex InterfaceAlias                     AddressFamily ConnectionState Forwarding
  1 Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1                 IPv4       Connected    Enabled
  1 Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1                 IPv6       Connected    Enabled
  6 Bluetooth-netwerkverbinding 2               IPv6    Disconnected    Enabled
  6 Bluetooth-netwerkverbinding 2               IPv4    Disconnected    Enabled
 12 VMware Network Adapter VMnet1               IPv4       Connected    Enabled
 12 VMware Network Adapter VMnet1               IPv6       Connected    Enabled
 15 LAN                                         IPv6       Connected    Enabled
 15 LAN                                         IPv4       Connected    Enabled
 16 VPN                                         IPv4    Disconnected    Enabled
 16 VPN                                         IPv6    Disconnected    Enabled
 22 VMware Network Adapter VMnet8               IPv6       Connected    Enabled
 22 VMware Network Adapter VMnet8               IPv4       Connected    Enabled
 26 Wireguard_Server                            IPv6       Connected    Enabled
 26 Wireguard_Server                            IPv4       Connected    Enabled
 27 vEthernet (WSL (Hyper-V firewall))          IPv6       Connected    Enabled
 27 vEthernet (WSL (Hyper-V firewall))          IPv4       Connected    Enabled
 33 vEthernet (Default Switch)                  IPv6       Connected    Enabled
 33 vEthernet (Default Switch)                  IPv4       Connected    Enabled

Windows "route print" output:
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.124     25
       10.20.10.0    255.255.255.0         On-link        10.20.10.1      5
       10.20.10.1  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.20.10.1    261
     10.20.10.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.20.10.1    261
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
     172.23.144.0    255.255.240.0         On-link      172.23.144.1   5256
     172.23.144.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.23.144.1   5256
   172.23.159.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.23.144.1   5256
      172.25.80.0    255.255.240.0         On-link       172.25.80.1   5256
      172.25.80.1  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.25.80.1   5256
    172.25.95.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.25.80.1   5256
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.124     27
    192.168.1.124  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.124    281
    192.168.1.175  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.20.10.1      5
     192.168.58.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.58.1    291
     192.168.58.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.58.1    291
   192.168.58.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.58.1    291
    192.168.107.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.107.1    291
    192.168.107.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.107.1    291
  192.168.107.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.107.1    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.1.124    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       172.25.80.1   5256
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      172.23.144.1   5256
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.58.1    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.107.1    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.124    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.25.80.1   5256
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.23.144.1   5256
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.58.1    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.107.1    291


As you have probably already discovered ip forwarding is disabled by default in Windows 10/11.
This is why you cannot ping any host in the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet over VPN.
Your problem is related to
this question, which has an answer on how to do it. :-)

Thanks alot man, It seems I totally oversaw the IPEnableRouter reg key. I'm not there yet, but now I can ping from Android peer to 192.168.1.124 (The Windows peer internal LAN address), but not yet other addresses. Tak skal du have!!

You also need to add a static route to your network to tell them that the network 10.20.10.1 is accessible via your windows host ... or else you have use masquerade techniques to hide the VPN network behind the windows host at least as seen from the rest of you LAN., but that is way more complicated than just adding a static route in your standard router.

Sigh:(, Just found out my ISP won't allow me to add static routes to 'their' router. Now I need Zyxel EX5601-T1 admin bypass or something :p

The alternative is you add the static router on all hosts that you want access to via VPN. A bit more tedious, but doable.

Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm afraid that option is off the table as well. The (IoT) device I'm trying to reach has no support for such advanced routing:) (ESP32C6 Tasmota Microcontroller via Wifi)

Ah well... Then there is only the option to purchase a router to put in between ISP router and your LAN. It works. I use Ubiquity for just that sort of things, and it even has support for Wireguard, though you may want do a bit of research first, since some of their routers requires a seperate host to manage them and they are not cheap.
